# Pattern for two similar functions without copying code

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have two functions that are almost the same except that there is an inversion of variable. I was wondering how to handle this without having duplicated code.

For example :

```
public static function getMajorRelative($tonality){
            $result = array_search($tonality,self::$_minorTonalities);
            return self::$_majorTonalities[$result];
}
```

And

```
public static function getMinorRelative($tonality){
        $result = array_search($tonality,self::$_majorTonalities);
        return self::$_minorTonalities[$result];
}
```

Anyone has had a similar conception issue?

Thanks,

Philippe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always pass in the array that you want to receive the result from:

```
public static function getRelative($tonality, $return_array) {
    //If returning minor, search major; Else, search minor.
    $array_to_search = ($return_array === self::$_minorTonalities ? self::$_majorTonalities : $_minorTonalities);
    $result = array_search($tonality, $array_to_search);
    return $return_array[$result];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll grab this one.

Answer (score 0):

2 similar (not identical) lines of code isn't really much of a duplication, but you could do:

```
protected static function getRelative($tonality, $tonalities1, $tonalities2) {
    $result = array_search($tonality, $tonalities1);
    return $tonalities2[$result];
}

public static function getMajorRelative($tonality){
    return self::getRelative($tonality, self::$_minorTonalities, self::$_majorTonalities);
}

public static function getMinorRelative($tonality){
    return self::getRelative($tonality, self::$_majorTonalities, self::$_minorTonalities);
}
```

if it really matters

You may also want some exception handling in case the value of $tonality doesn't exist in your arrays

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I simplified the code for the purpose of the example. It is more like 10 lines of code. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's much to improve. But if you want to, you could write it as one function:

```
public static function getRelative($chord,$tonality)
{
  $varName = '_'.($chord == 'major' ? 'major' : 'minor').'Tonalities';
  $result = array_search($tonality,self::${$varName});
  return self::${$varName}[$result];
}
```

You can call it as:

```
getRelative('major',$tonality);
getRelative('minor',$tonality);
```

Comment: Nice lean idea, although I think it increases the risk of bad calls by users of the class in my situation(e.g. someone could pass "rubbish"). Thanks anyway.